# toggle mute and unmute with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, opentok, tokbox

I'm trying to create a button for muting and un-mute.

Initially I have by button set up like this:

```
<i class="fa fa-microphone" id="audio"></i>
```

and what I want is that when you click it, the class becomes:

```
<i class="fa fa-microphone-slash" id="audio"></i>
```

now I have my javascript set up like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#audio').click(function() {
    publisher.publishAudio(false);
  });
});
```

which essentially mutes it, now I need to make it so that it can also unmute when I click on the button

Comment: Inside of your click function for #audio, since you're using jQuery, do $(this).toggleClass("fa-microphone").toggleClass("fa-microphone-slash");

Comment: perfect, now do you know how I can trigger the true false in publishAudio as-well?

Comment: There are several ways. You could use event handlers that listen to the class, but I've found sometimes they aren't reliable. If you want logic inside your click function there is suggest using $("#audio").hasClass("fa-microphone-slash") as the Boolean for an if statement, so if it is the slash class, unmute, else mute. I'll put all of this in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check if the publisher is sending video/audio on the stream it self like this:

```
publisher.stream.hasAudio
publisher.stream.hasVideo
```

then you can use the ! (bang) to invert it

```
publisher.publishAudio(!publisher.stream.hasAudio);
publisher.publishVideo(!publisher.stream.hasVideo);
```

so to toggle the class aswell you do someting like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var toggleAudioBtn = $('#audio')
    toggleAudioBtn.click(function() {
       toggleAudioBtn.toggleClass("fa-microphone-slash").toggleClass("fa-microphone");
       publisher.publishAudio(!publisher.stream.hasAudio); 
    });
 });
```

Comment: I think you have some mistakes in the code, that gives me an error with the semicolon after fa-microphone and then an unexpected identifier on publisher line?

Comment: sorry, forgot to remove the line above

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, I'd chain `toggleClass`, along with an if statement using `hasClass` for the logic:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#audio').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("fa-microphone-slash")) {
        publisher.publishAudio(true);
    } else {
        publisher.publishAudio(false);
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-microphone-slash");
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-microphone");

    publisher.publishAudio($(this).hasClass(""));
  });
});
```

If you want a DRY solution with no if statement, based on the class:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#audio').click(function() {
    publisher.publishAudio($(this).hasClass("fa-microphone-slash"));    
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-microphone-slash");
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-microphone");
  });
});
```

The second solution will just use the presence of the fa-microphone tag as a boolean for whether to perform a mute.

Comment: hey it seems to mute, but not unmute

Comment: Updated, see if that fixes your issue of it only working one way

Comment: progress. Now what happens if I do mute, it mutes, if I click unmute it is unmuted but the icon is still on unmute, and I'm unable to toggle them by clicking on it

Comment: I split the toggleClass calls out, is that solving your issue? I'm at work or I would do a live test.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know jquery that well but here's some simple javascript code to manipulate the class

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#audio').click(function() {
        var audio = document.querySelector("#audio");

        // get current class state
        var currentState = audio.getAttribute("class");

        // change class
        if(currentState === "fa fa-microphone"){
           audio.setAttribute("class", "fa fa-microphone-slash");
        }else{
           audio.setAttribute("class", "fa fa-microphone");
        }

    });
});
```